# How to make input invisible and flash screen in code block Macbook?

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks, user-input

I have build a simple maze game program, but it seems ugly when running it because i need print a new map for each movement. I want the game play in one map, how?

I know I need solve two problems, one is make the input invisible, second is flash the screen. but I use Macbook computer and codeblock complier, I can find few resource to solve these two problems. can anyone help?

```css
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void printmaze(char maze[12][12])
{
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<12;j++){
        cout<<maze[i][j];
}
cout<<endl;
}
}

int main(void)
{
    char maze[12][12]={
    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
    {'x',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x'},
    {'*',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x','x','x','x',' ','x'},
    {'x','x','x',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ','x'},
    {'x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','x','x',' ','x',' ','#'},
    {'x','x','x','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x'},
    {'x',' ',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x'},
    {'x','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x',' ','x'},
    {'x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ','x'},
    {'x','x','x','x','x','x',' ','x','x','x',' ','x'},
    {'x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ','x'},
    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
    };

  printmaze(maze);

int row=1, clo=0; //start location
char star='*';

char go;


while(cin>>go)
    {
    if(go=='w') {
            if(maze[row-1][clo] ==' ') {maze[row-1][clo]='*'; maze[row][clo]=' '; row--; printmaze(maze); cout<<endl;}
            else if(maze[row-1][clo]=='#') {cout<<"you win"<<endl; break;}
            }

    else if (go=='a') {
            if(maze[row][clo-1] ==' ') {maze[row][clo-1]='*';maze[row][clo]=' '; clo--; printmaze(maze);}
            else if(maze[row][clo-1]=='#') {cout<<"you win"<<endl; break;}
            }

    else if(go=='s') {
        if(maze[row+1][clo] ==' ') {maze[row+1][clo]='*';  maze[row][clo]=' ';row++; printmaze(maze);}
        else if(maze[row+1][clo]=='#') {cout<<"you win"<<endl; break;}
        }

    else if (go=='d') {
        if(maze[row][clo+1] ==' '){ maze[row][clo+1]='*';  maze[row][clo]=' '; clo++; printmaze(maze);}
        else if(maze[row][clo+1]=='#') {cout<<"you win"<<endl; break;}
        }
    else {cout<<"please input a valid letter to move"<<endl;}

    }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I have tried system("cls") and system("clear") to flash the screen but doesn't work. I also use getch() function to make the input letter invisible still not work. there may be header or complier not suitable.

Comment: Is this run on OSX only, or also on Windows?  (If OSX only, you could use ncurses).

Comment: Thanks Dickey for your reply, This is OSx only, I have used #include<ncurses.h> then system("clear"), but still doesn't work.

Comment: My suggestion was more along the lines of a rewrite: (a) using ncurses you would use printw rather than redirecting to cout, and use the erase or clear functions provided by ncurses (rather than the command-line "clear", which is also provided by ncurses).